# User authentication with mobile number and OTP in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-sessions, one-time-password

I have two types of users. 
 - Customer. 
 - Vendor. 
For Customers, I've already created custom user class where login happens through email and password. But, Vendors do not have email id and password. All vendor accounts are manually created by the django admin. Vendor class looks like this.

```
class Vendor():
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, required=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    .
    .
```

What's the best way to implement OTP login for Vendors? Vendors usually login through an android/iOS app which communicates with the server using REST apis. Currently, I've created one more model to store 6 digit OTP password. Vendor enters his mobile no, he gets the OTP through SMS. Once he enters it I'm matching it with stored OTP key from the OTP table and sending success status. But ideally, I've to create an user session and send it along with success status. 
Is there any plugin in Django to do this?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth import login, login(request, user_with_that_mobile_number), hope this helps :)

Comment: But Vendor is not a django user. He doesn't have username, password, email id etc. How do I associate session details and other authentication related functions to a normal django model ?

Comment: IMHO, as per my limited knowledge, you are re-inventing the wheel by not associating the vendor to any user. I would suggest associating a User instance to a vendor instance or writing a custom user model. Also, I would be interested if someone comes up with a different solution. Thanks