# User Authentication with mobile number and OTP

Tags: android, python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

At the outset let me state that I am not an expert in Django and will really appreciate any help. I am building a simple e-commerce application backend in Django. The clients will be a web-app and an android app.

I don't want to have user defined passwords but automatically generated OTPs that will be sent to the users whenever they attempt login. I have derived my user model from the classes PermissionsMixin and models.Model classes and am using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to write all the APIs.

I had a look at the [django-otp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-otp) library but think it is built for two-factor authentication which is not suitable for me.

One easy solution I thought is to first obtain the username (which is the mobile number in my case) and then randomly generate an OTP at the server. This OTP can be stored as the password for that particular user (in the password field).

Then after the user enters the OTP it can work exactly like a normal username / password would. Can you please suggest if this is a good idea, or is there a better means of doing this?

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407609/user-authentication-with-mobile-number-and-otp-in-django-1-7) has been asked earlier but has not been answered in detail.

Comment: Kindly verify this link it may helpful for u http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-1/

Comment: Thanks! The link corroborates what I have proposed above as a methodology. Only caveat I would really like a Django Expert to share if what I proposed is neat